# Java IntelliJ No encuentra carpetas

Tags: java

estoy tratando de hacer una búsqueda de directorios a partir del curso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs9ISry4o10

El detalle es que todo parece correr bien en el vídeo, pero cuando yo trato de correrlo, me dice que no encuentra ningún directorio.

El código para buscar directorios es:

```
private String[] getFolderNames(String basePath) {
    File resource = new File(basePath);
    String[] directories = resource.list(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File current, String name) {
                return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
            }
        });
    return directories;
}
```

Donde *basePath* lo tengo como `/sprites/units`. EL directorio es:
*C:> Usuarios >MiUsuario> IdeaProjects> Proyecto>resources>sprites>units*

Se supone que dentro debería encontrar dos carpetas llamadas *dave* y *matt* como indica en el vídeo, pero el método sólo me devuelve un valor nulo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer una búsqueda efectiva?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: `/sprites/units` te listará los ficheros de `C:\sprites\units`, que no existe. El `/` inicial indica que es una ruta absoluta

Comment: @SJuan76 Muchas gracias por tu comentario, el detalle es que, cuando trato de colocarlo relativo "./sprites/units"  hace que ni siquiera se encuentre "resource" y me lo deja en nulo

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` te dirá en qué directorio está ejecutándose el proceso.